# Property 'x' does not exist on type ... - Promise syntax - TS2339

Tags: angular, typescript

I met a problem I didn't understand with Typescript. I found another topics with that kind of problem but even that i dont know how to resolve my problem.
I can console.log userCredential.user.metadata.b easily, but even that I got a error: Property 'b' does not exist on type 'UserMetadata'. Can u explain me what here is wrong?

Here the part of code

```
<pre>
 login(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
       return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
           .then(userCredential => {
               const creationTime: number = userCredential.user.metadata.b; // <-here is a problem
               console.log('creationTinme', creationTime);
               this.handleAuthentication(
                   userCredential.user.email,
                   userCredential.user.uid,
                   'xxx',
                   creationTime
                   // metadata.creationTime expiresInuser.metadata
               );
           })
           .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
           });
</pre>
```

Thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is inferring the type of `userCredential` based on the type information from the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method. (Which is good, that's what you want.) The error is telling you that the type it's inferred for `userCredential` does have a `user` property with a `metadata` property, but the type of the `metadata` property doesn't have a property called `b`. The object has that property at runtime (since you can see it in `console.log`), but the type information for it doesn't say it has it.

To fix it, you'll need to change the type used by `signInWithEmailAndPassword` so that it gives `metadata` a `b` property (or an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures), if that makes more sense in your use case).

Comment: i'm beginner and i don't understand the resolve now, but i will read  and learn about it and after that i will answer , thank you